# Why can't Kinetic friction and static friction have the same coefficient?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

Why can't the coefficient of kinetic and static friction be equal?

For example, if both types of friction are of magnitude 50N and I apply a force of 50N, surfaces are still interlocked and the object is still at rest

if I apply 50.1N, surfaces are no longer interlocked and the object starts to move forward with a force of 0.1N

Comment: What makes you believe that they aren't equal -- or nearly so -- in some cases?  You stated a case where there's a 500:1 ratio between kinetic and static friction, but it doesn't always have to be that high (making it 1:1 may take some advanced materials science, though).

Comment: There are materials with the same static and dynamic coefficients (Delrin if I recall properly is one).

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing in principle preventing a surface from having the same coefficients of kinetic and static friction - in fact, many introductory textbook problems will have students "consider a surface with $\mu_s=\mu_k=\mu$ ..." because it leads to nice math. In reality, though, the static friction coefficient is always higher than the kinetic friction coefficient, which you can consider as an empirical result. The fact that $\mu_s>\mu_k$ for real materials leads to [stick-slip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stick-slip_phenomenon#:%7E:text=The%20stick%E2%80%93slip%20phenomenon%2C%20also,are%20sliding%20over%20each%20other) behavior, which has important applications in engineering.

Answer (score 1):

static friction is the frictional force that needs one needs to overcome in order to move an object but kinetic friction only comes into play when the object is moving and this force is always acting in the opposite direction to the relative motion of the body. The applications of the 2 types of frictions are different hence they do not have the same coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

> if I apply 50.1N, surfaces are no longer interlocked and the object
> starts to move forward with a force of 0.1N

We can know the resultant force by the body acceleration $F_R = ma$. What happens is that once it starts to move, the acceleration is not almost zero. It jumps suddenly to some value.

It can be easily observed placing a body on a plane surface and gradually increasing the plane inclination. After reaching a limit angle, the body suddenly moves down with a reasonable acceleration, not a very small one. That means: once overcoming the static friction, the friction force is now well below the gravity component along the incline, so that the net force along the incline is well above zero.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had an interface where the static friction coefficient was less than the kinetic friction coefficient.  Take this surface and put it on an inclined plane, then tilt it until the appropriate component of the weight is just barely large enough to overcome the static friction. Since we've assumed the kinetic friction is larger, the new kinetic friction will overcome the weight, and the object will just stop.

Since the object can't start moving until the larger of the two friction forces is overcome, the static (not-moving) friction coefficient must be equal to or larger than the kinetic (moving) coefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure that a kinetic friction coefficient higher than the static friction can be sensibly defined.  At that point, the simplistic kinetic vs. static friction model would break down.  Note that the static & kinetic friction model that's taught in introductory physics courses is incredibly simplified compared to reality -- there are models that answer questions like "what counts as moving?" and "how long do you have to be stopped, really?" and it turns out the answers are different for different combinations of materials.

Comment: At least circa 1995-ish, the sophomore physics model of friction was also a great way to make Matlab/Simulink freeze up, and take a Windows machine with it.  I suspect they're more robust to that now, though.

Comment: @TimWescott Right, that was my point. A higher kinetic than static friction doesn't make sense in this simple model. I didn't want to explore much more of the space of better models, but it's good that you have briefly described a couple.